# How do I find minimum value for following problem in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, statistics

Here I have a list as following:

```
[0.40540540540540543, 0.40540540540540543, 0.08108108108108109, 0.40540540540540543, 0.40540540540540543, 0.43243243243243246, 0.43243243243243246, 0.40540540540540543, 0.40540540540540543]
```

From the above list we can observe that most of the values are in the range of 0.4 to 0.5. I want to write a piece of code that will figure out the range for most of numbers in the list(that lie in the range) and find the minimum value that lies in the range.

Comment: The `min` builtin function?

Comment: What, *exactly*, do you mean by "near 0.4"?

Comment: Assuming a difference of 0.05 or less qualifies as "near": `min([x for x in mylist if abs(x - 0.4) < 0.05])`

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica "near 0.4" is just my observation. From the given list we can observe that most values in the list in the range of 0.4 to 0.5 . Here  I ONLY KNOW that I have a list and I also KNOW that most of the elements in the list will lie in certain range. So I have to FIGURE OUT such a range with interval of 0.1 and then from this range I've to find out the minimum value. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @JohnGordon Here I do not know the value '0.4'. It's something that I observed. I want to find out the range where most of values in the list fall(Here we can observe that most of them fall in range of 0.4 to 0.5) where interval for the range is 0.1. So once the range is obtained I just have to find closest number near the lower limit of the range.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should define what you mean by outliers by computing the z-value (See https://www.statology.org/remove-outliers-python/ for more details)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
A = np.array([0.40540540540540543, 0.40540540540540543, 0.08108108108108109, 0.40540540540540543,
              0.40540540540540543, 0.43243243243243246, 0.43243243243243246, 0.40540540540540543,
              0.40540540540540543])
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(A))
A_clean = np.array([A[i] for i in range(len(z)) if z[i] < 2])
```

Normally we define outliers as either `z > 3` or `z < -3`, but for your example `z < 2` would work.

Comment: You don't need to use NumPy just to take a minimum. Python already has a `min` builtin. Also, this doesn't account for the question's vague "near 0.4" qualifier.

Comment: (If you're already using NumPy, you should use `numpy.min` or the `numpy.ndarray.min` method instead of the built-in `min`, but if you're working without NumPy, the regular `min` builtin is appropriate.)

Comment: Sorry, but this not something I meant to find out. You can check the question's description and comments to understand the problem.

Comment: @Atharva I would sort the list first.  After that thing should be more obvious on what are the outliers.

Comment: @Teera Yes I stumbled upon a article on outliers and I'm basically rejecting the outlier.   If you want you can edit your answer, I will mark the outlier solution as correct. _Thanks a ton_.

Comment: @Atharva I have edited my solution -- hope this helps.